# JavaScript To Do list with localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make my own To Do list using `JavaScript` and `localStorage`. After writing the input and pressing the send button, the item will be added and display on the screen. A delete button will appear next to the item. But I can't do that to delete the thing after pressing the delete button.

`HTML` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do list</title>
</head>

<body>

    <input id="inpKey" type="text">
    <input id="inpValue" type="text">
    <button type="button" id="add">Add</button>

    <div id="items"> </div>

</body>

<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

`JavaScript` code:

```
const inpKey = document.getElementById("inpKey");
const inpValue = document.getElementById("inpValue");
const add = document.getElementById("add");
const items = document.getElementById("items");


add.onclick = function() {
    const key = inpKey.value;
    const value = inpValue.value;

    if (key && value) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
        location.reload();
    }
};

for (let a = 0; a < localStorage.length; a++) {
    const key = localStorage.key(a);
    const value = localStorage.getItem(key);

    items.innerHTML += `${key}: ${value}` + "<button type='button' onclick='deleteItem()'>Delete</button><br>";
}

function deleteItem() {
    localStorage.removeItem();
    location.reload();
}
```

Comment: I think you need to add the key of the item in the removeItem function something like that : ```localStorage.removeItem(key)```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the key to delete item:

```
onclick='deleteItem(${key})'
```

then

```
function deleteItem(key) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the below with your line

```
items.innerHTML += `${key}: ${value} <button type='button' onclick='deleteItem(${key})'>Delete</button><br>`;
```

then

```
function deleteItem(key) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this:

```
items.innerHTML += `${key}: ${value} <button type='button' onclick='deleteItem(${key})'>Delete</button><br>`;
```

and this

```
function deleteItem(key) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
}
```

like in answer, but when i click delete, the console shows: **Uncaught ReferenceError: "key" is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:21)**